# Animate Xaringan figures and text

Tags: css, r, animate.css, xaringan

I want to animate some elements inside the slides in my Xaringan presentation.

I am aware on how to animate slide transitions as especified in the link below (https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/animate-xaringan-slide-transitions/).

What I really want is the possibility of using such animations in a text or image of a slide.

When looking at the *animate.css* file I can see some classes, for example:

`.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}`

But when I try to use in RMardown like this:

`.pulse[Some text]`

Nothing happens.

I was hoping for a solution which would ideally allow me to choose all the possible animations (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `.pulse[Some text]` it convert it to `<span class="pulse">Some text</span>`. A couple of things to animate it here:

- you need to add the class `animated`
- change it to `div` instead. You can do this by starting `]` *in a new line*.

So this should work (given that you have `animate.css` included):

```
.pulse.animated[Some text
]
```

Comment: I was interested that this was the second answer which you had helped that I've checked you blog. What a lovely great surprise. Your package anicon does exactly what I wanted (and much more) in such an easy way.  I would suggest anyone reading this thread to use it.  So, to animate text (or pretty much everything), I will use anicon.  As for my slides I will use the following approach:  `r anicon::nia("some text", animate = "flash)`

Comment: Ah yes `anicon` does do animated text/icon/pic! `animate.css` has more fantastic animations which I hope to integrate in the future. Comments to make `anicon` welcome :)